# Why are paths to file in project extended in VS code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, path

I have cloned a project from GitHub to VS code. There is a folder data in that project which contains file train.csv. But when I try to read it in .py file in that project, path `data/train.csv` doesn't work. When I copy path of file it shows `/Users/me/Desktop/my_project/data/train.csv`. Why does it happen? And how to fix it?